# Как с помощью 1С делать авторизацию в dropbox?

Tags: api, 1с, dropbox, dropbox-api

Написал код таким образом:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура АвторизацияВДропбокс(Команда)
    ДанныеАвторизации = Новый Структура;
    AppId = "Здесь App key";
    AppS = "Здесь App secret"; 
    ДанныеАвторизации.Вставить("AppId", AppId);
    ДанныеАвторизации.Вставить("AppS", AppS);
    
    WinHttp = Новый COMОбъект("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
    WinHttp.Open("POST", "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id="+AppId+"&response_type=code&token_access_type=offline", Ложь);
    WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_version=""2.0"", oauth_signature_method=""PLAINTEXT"", oauth_consumer_key=""" + ДанныеАвторизации.AppId + """, oauth_signature=""" + ДанныеАвторизации.AppS + "&""");
    WinHttp.Send();
    Сообщить(WinHttp.Status);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Но почему-то авторизация не проходит, выводит статус 404. Как делать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Отправка POST запроса:

```
   WinHttp.Open("POST", "http://yandex.ru/yandsearch", Ложь);
   WinHttp.Send("lr=5&text=test"); //передача POST-параметров
   Если WinHttp.Status = 200 Тогда
      Сообщить(WinHttp.ResponseText);
   Иначе
      Сообщить("HTTP " + WinHttp.Status + " " + WinHttp.StatusText);
      Возврат;
   КонецЕсли;
```